# preciso comparar o valor da ultima célula preenchida com a antepenúltima

Tags: vba, excel-vba, web-scraping, range

ola agradeço a atenção.

preciso comparar o valor da ultima célula preenchida com a antepenúltima.
 caso o valor seje diferente quero continuar com o valor atual 
 caso seje = colocar a palavra erro

isto esta sendo nescessrio pois no meu codigo esta carregando o resultado da pesquisa anterior

```
.Document.all("cpf").innerText = Range("a" & linha)

.Document.all("btn_consultar").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Range("g" & linha) = IE.Document.all("teste1").innerText
Range("b" & linha) = IE.Document.all("teste2").innerText
Range("d" & linha) = IE.Document.all("teste3").innerText
Range("e" & linha) = IE.Document.all("teste"5).innerText
Range("f" & linha) = IE.Document.all("tesste2").innerText
Range("g" & linha) = IE.Document.all("5353fsf").innerText

menos1 = linha - 1
linha = linha + 1

MsgBox ("linha")
MsgBox ("menos1")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))





Wend
      Wend
          Wend

  End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thays boa noite, essa comparação está em coluna ou linha, nessa faixa tem células em branco?

Comment: oi paulo boa noite, estão em coluna e uma sequencia de cpf que jogo no sistema e me retorna um valor na celula  Range("d" & linha) = IE.Document.all("msisdnCliente").innerText
porem o resultado esta se repetindo quando negativo. ai gostaria de comparar o resultado com a linha anterior se for igual a anterior para preencher com erro ou algo assim

Answer (score 1):

Thays espero que o trecho de código ajude

```
If linha >= 2 And Range("D" & linha).Value <> Empty Then
'inicia comparação a partir da linha 2, já que a comparação é entre a linha atual e a atual-1
    If Range("D" & linha - 1).Value = Range("D" & linha).Value Then
        '<seu código aqui>
        Debug.Print Range("D" & linha).Value, Range("D" & linha).Address
    End If
End If
```

Comment: ok muito obrigada.

Comment: Estou a disposição

Comment: ajudou sim funcionou conforme o esperado Y vlw

Comment: @ThaysLima Favor ler [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)